# Lawnchair across multiple pages

Tags: javascript, json, lawnchair

I have been playing around with using Lawnchair in phonegap but can only get the data to load on the same page it was saved.

Is this how Lawnchair works?

I have tried console.log to log the data that I have saved using Lawnchair on the page that it was saved in, but as soon as I move to another page with the same retrieval code it does not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similiar problem when building a two-page HTML5 'app' based on Local Storage.

I made the mistake of not including the 'dom' plugin alongside the `lawnchair.js` file. (I thought it was somehow already built-in to `Lawnchair` because its the default storage system).

See the first paragraph of [this post](http://brian.io/lawnchair/downloads/)..

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I got it narrowed down to this and another bug that was caused from using something different in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
var res = Lawnchair({name:'key',adapter:'dom'},function(e){
});

res.all(function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
      Get data using data[i].value.fieldname.....
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it ended up being a bug from using jQuery mobile and with the DOM plugin with Lawnchair. I created a new dummy application and it worked first time. But again, thank you for the response, the loop may actually help me with something else.